# How can I set content div align right?

Tags: html, css

My code and demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/tptrfph1/

I want to set `<div class="right">` to be align right. I try `margin: 0`, it does not work.

My code is jsfiddle is static

Actually my code is dynamic like this :

```
<div class="global">
            <div class="left">
                <div style="width: {{ $length_of_text }}mm; margin-left: -15px !important;"> 
                    abcdeeeeeeeeeeeee <br>
                    cdeeeeeeeaberccccccccc
                </div>
                <hr style="max-width: {{ $length_of_line }}mm; margin-left:0; height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div style="width: {{ $length_of_text_two }}mm;"> 
                    <table>
                        <tr style="padding-right:35px">
                            <td>Attachment</td>
                            <td align="right">Latter Fans 023/PT</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Number</td>
                            <td align="right">B / 123 / I / 2016</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td align="right">12 May 2017</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <hr style="max-width: {{ $length_of_line_two }}mm; margin-left:0 height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">

            </div>
        </div>
```

The variable of `$length_of_text`, `$length_of_line`, `$length_of_text_two`, `$length_of_line_two` is input of user

I want `<div class="right">` to be in the far right corner. So when you grow up, it's left.

I try `margin: 0` and `text align right`, but it does not work

How can I solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but from my assumption, you want the `<div class="right">` to be on the far right? get rid of `margin-left:75%;` and add `float:right;` I think that's what you want right?

Comment: "So when you grow up, it's left."  What does this mean?

Comment: @McHat, If width of`{{ $length_of_text_two }}` and `{{ $length_of_line_two }}` increased, it will elongate and shift left

Comment: @Jorden1337, I'm still confused, because I do not master css

Comment: i am confused too. try **<table style="width: 80%;">** or **<table style="width: 100%;">**

Comment: @techLove, You must read my question correctly

Comment: @samueltoh why don't you use flex, as flex property specifies the length of the item, relative to the rest of the flexible items inside the same container. If you check here in my demo. http://codepen.io/femkhan/pen/dNXOwd?editors=1100

Comment: @Maqk, If width of{{ $length_of_text_two }} and {{ $length_of_line_two }} increased, it will elongate and shift left

Comment: @Maqk, I try in html, it works. But in pdf, it does not work. The div right and div left not display. Seems flex not executed in pdf

Comment: You try see answer from blecaf. I want to make like that. But I want to not use flex. Because flex not working in pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove the `margin-left: 75%;` line, your `div` will be aligned on the right side.  See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tptrfph1/2/).

```
div.right {
    /* margin-left: 75%; */
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to move the text header over to the right as well, add `float: right;` and `clear: both;` to the `div.right` style (they've been added into [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tptrfph1/2/)):

```
div.right {
    /* margin-left: 75%; */
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @reginold, You try see : div in `<div class="left">`. I want to make `<div class="right">`like that. But its position on the right. So, width of `{{ $length_of_text_two }}` and `{{ $length_of_line_two }}` increased, it will elongate and shift left

Comment: You try see answer from blecaf. I want to make like that. But I want to not use flex. Because flex not working in pdf

Answer (score 0):

By adding the float property you can position the div in respective position. i.e in your case one div in right and another in left. Text align is for aligning the text.

```
div.left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

div.right {
    float:right
    text-align:right
}
```

[check this js fiddle modified](https://jsfiddle.net/tptrfph1/3/)

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: @Saajan, You try see : `div` in `<div class="left">`. I want to make `<div class="right">`like that. But its position on the right. So, width of{{ $length_of_text_two }} and {{ $length_of_line_two }} increased, it will elongate and shift left

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i guess i did the correction. Thank you

Comment: @samueltoh i think its working as you want it... Try adding width to the div with right class,its getting elongated towards left.

Comment: @Saajan, I want when width of `<div class="right">` = 0, the position on the right. No on the left. When the width increased, it will elongate and shift left

Comment: @Saajan, You try see answer from blecaf. I want to make like that. But I want to not use flex. Because flex not working in pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about old browsers

```
.right div {
justify-content: flex-end;
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I try in html, it works. But in pdf, it does not work. The div right and div left not display. Seems flex not executed in pdf

Comment: You try see answer from blecaf. I want to make like that. But I want to not use flex. Because flex not working in pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can you flex box. Looking at your fiddle i guess this {{ $length_of_line_two }} is to increase the width of the div after calculating the lenght of the tex. Using flex the width will increase and drop to the next line when it cant occupy that space anylonger. See **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qshd5vr6/)**

Report

```
    <style type="text/css"> 

        .tg { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; }
        .tg td { padding: 2px 1px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; overflow: hidden; word-break: normal; }
        .tg th { word-wrap: break-word; padding: 4px 3px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; overflow: hidden; word-break: normal; }
        .tg .tg-3wr7 { text-align: center; }
        .tg .tg-ti5e { font-size: 9px; text-align: center; }
        .tg .tg-rv4w { font-size: 9px; }
        body {  
            font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
            font-size: 9px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto
        }

        div.global{
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        div.center {
            margin-left: 27%;
            width: 485px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        div.signature {
            margin-left: 70%;
            width: 250px; 
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .tg tr.content td{
            border-top: none !important;
            border-bottom: none !important;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="global">
        <div class="left">
            <div style="max-width: 80mm; margin-left: -15px !important;"> 
                abcdeeeeeeeeeeeee <br>
                cdeeeeeeeaberccccccccc
            </div>
            <hr style="max-width: 80mm; margin-left:0; height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <div style="max-width: 80mm;"> 
                <table>
                    <tr style="padding-right:35px">
                        <td>Attachment</td>
                        <td align="right">Latter Fans 023/PT</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number</td>
                        <td align="right">B / 123 / I / 2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td align="right">12 May 2017</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <hr style="max-width: 80mm; margin-left:0 height:1px; border:none; color:#333;background-color:#333;">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        Budget execution report <br>
        PERIOD : 1 JANUARY To 31 December 2017
    </div>
    <br>
    <table class="tg">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">NO<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 1<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 2<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 3<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 4<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 5<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 6<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 7<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 8<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 9<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 10<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 11<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 12<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" colspan="2">KOLOM 13<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">KOLOM 14<br></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">1<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">2<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">3<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">4<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">5<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">6<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">7<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">8<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">9<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">10<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">11<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">12<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">13<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" colspan="2">14<br></td>
                <td class="tg-3wr7" rowspan="2">15<br></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>            
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="signature">
        London,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10 May 2017<br><br><br><br><br><br>
        Eden Hazard<br>
        Chelsea Player
    </div>
</body>
```

```
div.global {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.left {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
div.right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: I try in html, it works. But in pdf, it does not work. The div right and div left not display. Seems flex not executed in pdf